# Google API with RIOT API fail JSON parsing

Tags: java, api, google-api

Some one can help me here ?

```
Exception in thread "main" net.rithms.riot.api.RiotApiException: Failed to parse the JSON response
at net.rithms.riot.api.request.Request.getDto(Request.java:288)
at net.rithms.riot.api.request.Request.getDto(Request.java:252)
at net.rithms.riot.api.EndpointManager.callMethodAndReturnDto(EndpointManager.java:53)
at net.rithms.riot.api.RiotApi.getLeagueById(RiotApi.java:1467)
at lol.simone.pescatore.riot.App.main(App.java:28)
```

This error is triggered by Google API here:

```
package lol.simone.pescatore.riot;

import java.util.List;

import net.rithms.riot.api.ApiConfig;
import net.rithms.riot.api.RiotApi;
import net.rithms.riot.api.RiotApiException;
import net.rithms.riot.api.endpoints.league.dto.LeagueItem;
import net.rithms.riot.api.endpoints.match.dto.Match;
import net.rithms.riot.api.endpoints.match.dto.MatchList;
import net.rithms.riot.api.endpoints.match.dto.MatchReference;
import net.rithms.riot.api.endpoints.match.dto.TeamBans;
import net.rithms.riot.api.endpoints.match.dto.TeamStats;
import net.rithms.riot.api.endpoints.summoner.dto.Summoner;
import net.rithms.riot.constant.Platform;

//  lega -> lista summoner della lega -> summoner -> lista match del summoner -> dal match prendo le match references -> prendo anche i partecipanti -> prendo tutte le statistiche dal match -> butto tutto nel CSV

public class App {

    public static final String CSV_PATH = "C:\\Users\\gzampaol\\Lol";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws RiotApiException {
        ApiConfig config = new ApiConfig().setKey("RGAPI-92701727-09f4-4e68-8c75-c903715fb112S");
        RiotApi api = new RiotApi(config);


        List<LeagueItem> participant = api.getLeagueById(Platform.EUW, "000115d0-45ad-11e8-a09c-c81f66dbb56c").getEntries();
        MatchList matchList = new MatchList();
        String mapName = new String();
        TeamBans bans = new TeamBans();
```

It break on

```
List<LeagueItem> participant = api.getLeagueById(Platform.EUW, "000115d0-45ad-11e8-a09c-c81f66dbb56c").getEntries();
```

And this is what i found

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_OBJECT at line 1 column 2 path $
```

I use Eclipse with JDK and i'm using com.google.code.gson v2.8.5

Body response: https://pastebin.com/ac3d6sRL

The error generates here

```
dto = new Gson().fromJson(response.getBody(), type);
```

How can i resolve this ?

(p.s. I am self-taught so I do not know many things. Please be as explicit as possible. Thank you <3)

Comment: I'm struggling to under the connection between a Google API and RIOT API? What Google API are you using? Can you provide a sample of your code where the error is being raised? What platform are you running your code on?

Comment: Done, I hope I have added everything you asked for